# flash builder 4.5 , sqlite database query issue

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am working with flex 4.5 for an iOS application. I'm trying to make a login screen. Here I have attached my code:

The login button's click handler:

```
protected function btnlogin_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    user();
}
```

Which calls this function:

```
private function user():void
{
    sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
    sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("SchoolSeries.db"));
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    stmt.text = "select User_Name from USER_NEW where User_Password = :password" 
    stmt.parameters[":password"] = password.text ;
    stmt.execute();
    var result11:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
    DataModel.getInstance().connection = sqlConnection;
    //statuslable1.text = (String(result11.data[0].User_Conform_Password));
    if ((String(result11.data[0].User_Name)) == username.text)
    {
        //VerifyLogin();
        navigator.pushView(SummaryView,{unm:username.text});
    }
    else
    {
        statuslabelpass.visible = false;
        statuslabel1.visible = false;
        statuslabel.visible =true;
        statuslabel.text = "Username & Password do not match";
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm not validating the fields the way I'd like. If I enter the correct password but a wrong username then and then only I can get a message like "username and password do not match". But if I enter a correct username and an incorrect password then I do not get any message.

If I write another function for validating the password, and call it from button click, at that time that function has not been called even.

```
private function passwrd():void
{
    sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
    sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("SchoolSeries.db"));
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    stmt.text = "select User_Password from USER_NEW where User_Name = :username" 
    stmt.parameters[":username"] = username.text ;
    stmt.execute();
    var result11:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
    DataModel.getInstance().connection = sqlConnection;
    //statuslable1.text = (String(result11.data[0].User_Conform_Password));
    if ((String(result11.data[0].User_Password)) == password.text)
    {
        navigator.pushView(SummaryView,{unm:username.text});
    }
    else
    {
        statuslabel.visible = false;
        statuslabel1.visible = false;
        statuslabelpass.visible =true;
        statuslabelpass.text = "Username & Password do not match";  
    }
}
```

What should I do to velidate both field of sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

Pass both parameters to your query and then check to see if 0 or 1 records are returned.

```
stmt.text = "select User_Password from USER_NEW where User_Name = :username and User_Password = :password" 
stmt.parameters[":username"] = username.text ;
stmt.parameters[":password"] = password.text ;

if (result11.data.length > 0)
{
    //valid credentials
}
else
{
    //Username & Password do not match
}
```

After looking at your user() function a second time, i see a major bug in it.  If you have 2 users that chose the same password, one of them would never be able to log in.  The query would return 2 records, but you are only checking username against the record in position [0], so the user that gets returned in position [1] would never validate.  You really should pass both parameters in the same query.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I am not comparing its length here. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @NaveedMansuri The length comparison is checking to see if any results are returned from the query.  If you pass in correct username and password the query will return 1 record, so result11.data.length will be greater than 0.  If either username or password are wrong, the query will return 0 records and you can display your error message.